# JavaScript regex replace - but only part of matched string?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, typography

I have the following replace function

```
myString.replace(/\s\w(?=\s)/,"$1\xA0");
```

The aim is to take single-letter words (e.g. prepositions) and add a non-breaking space after them, instead of standard space.

However the above $1 variable doesn't work for me. It inserts text "$1 " instead of a part of original matched string + nbsp.

What is the reason for the observed behaviour? Is there any other way to achieve it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$1 doesn't work because you don't have any capturing subgroups.

The regular expression should be something like `/\b(\w+)\s+/`.

Comment: yes, that "capturing group" was the piece I was missing. Thank you very much!

Comment: Thank you. It's not well documented and I couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 5):

Seems you want to do something like this:

```
myString.replace(/\s(\w)\s/,"$1\xA0");
```

but that way you will loose the whitespace before your single-letter word. So you probably want to also include the first `\s` in the capturing group.

Comment: hey, this works like charm! awesome, thank you so much. I didn't know about "capturing group" but was suspicious there's something like that.